# Failed to find target with hash tag string 'android-19' even when android 19 has not used

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, android-sdk-tools

I have a android project imported from eclipse. Gradle is,

```
compiledSdkVersion 23

buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig{

minSdkVersion 14

targetedSdkVersion 21}
```

I have installed sdk version 23. But when the Gradle builds, it shows an error,

`failed to find target with hash tag string 'android-19'`

I need to build this project without using version 19. Please someone help me to solve this problem.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Last time I had this problem, I solved it by uninstalling API 23 and installing it again.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a `project.properties` file with `target=android-19`, modify it with android tools or manually